# How to ignore JSON serialization of constant properties using System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, system.text.json

I am trying to migrate from **Newtonsoft.Json** to **System.Text.Json**. "[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]" works for ignoring the constant property during serialization, but "[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]" does not. I wonder if there is a work around.

So I am trying to migrate from;

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MyClass: MyBaseClass
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public const string MyConstString = "lets get rid of netwonsoft dependency";

    public string data;

    public String(string data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

to;

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class MyClass: MyBaseClass
{
    [JsonIgnore] // Error
    public const string MyConstString = "lets get rid of netwonsoft dependency";

    public string data;

    public String(string data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

The error description is;
*"Attribute 'JsonIgnore' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations."*

Is it because System.Text.Json does not support such use of JsonIgnore, or am I missing something? 
I could not find anything useful on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to) regarding this issue. Would you have any ideas?

Comment: a property declaration usually has a getter and/or a setter. Can you try changing it to `public string MyConstString { get; } = "your string";`

Comment: `System.Text.Json` won't serialise a `const` anyway, you don't need that attribute here.

Comment: In fact neither will Newtonsoft, it's not clear why you have this attribute on your `const` in the first place?

Comment: Perhaps a bigger problem you have is that the new serialiser doesn't serialise fields, meaning you need to change them to properties.

Comment: Newtonsoft will only serialise `const` values if you explicitly mark them with the `[JsonProperty]` attribute.

Comment: You can switch your fields to properties and use [`IgnoreReadOnlyProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#exclude-all-read-only-properties)

Answer (score 4):

The JSON.Net [`[JsonIgnore]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) attribute has it's [usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/attributeusage) set to `AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field` meaning it can be used on a `const`. However the new .NET Core API version of [`[JsonIgnore]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=netcore-3.1) is set to `AttributeTargets.Property` only. That means you can only use it on a *property*.

Having said that, JSON.Net will not serialise `const` values unless you explicitly tell it to serialise by using a [`[JsonProperty]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) attribute, which then makes adding another attribute to ignore it a little peculiar anyway.

For example, JSON.Net will serialise the class you have in your question as:

```
{"data":"foo"}
```

Whereas the serialiser in `System.Text.Json` will give you this:

```
{}
```

So another problem is that the newer API doesn't serialise *fields*. The takeaway from this is that you should be using modern C# techniques, and that means using properties, for example:

```
public string data { get; set; }
```